# Current playback queue for MPMusicPlayerController?

Tags: ios, mpmusicplayercontroller

I realize that there's two ways to set the playback queue (with a query or with a collection of MPMediaItems), but once this has been done, is there a way to access the queue on MPMusicPlayerController without having to retain it myself?

I'd like to avoid the hassle of maintaining the queue myself if it's public on the controller. So far all I can get access to is the currently playing item. I can also get the index of the currently playing item, but this is useless without a queue. (Which I find odd that they give you and index, but no queue).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This property unfortunately is not exposed on the MPMusicPlayerController class. The only alternative is to set the queue yourself.